# why $\mathbb{R}$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

why $\mathbb{R}$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

---

can anyone please tell me the reason for the above question though it is not a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If $F$ is a field, then $F$ is the splitting field of the empty familiy of polynomials over $F$. :P

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}$ is the splitting field of $\{x-1\}$. Indeed, all the roots of $x-1$ are in $\mathbb{R}$, and they generate $\mathbb{R}$ an an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. That said, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a splitting field for $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$) is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is not. In particular, $e$ is not even algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Berci Unless I am misunderstanding you, that is going the wrong way. I tried to reason that $\mathbb{R}$ can't be a splitting field, else $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. You jus showed that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\ne \mathbb{R}$. There is still no reason to believe $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ can't be algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

Each field $F$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $X\in F[X]$. So $F$ is a splitting field over itself.